# Xcode backward compatibility

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, ios4, xcode3.2

I want to upgrade my Xcode 3.2.3 to Xcode 4.0 
but I want to confirm one thing about my current project code.
Will upgrading cause problems with my current code ? Can I still run the code made by Xcode 3.2.3 and run it and modify it with Xcode 4.0 ?

If you have experience regarding this please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode 4 uses the same project structure as Xcode 3. You can switch back and forth between them without any trouble.