# Can I run Xcode 4 Project in Xcode 3?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I download the One Example which had been in Xcode 4. I have Xcode 3 therefore, I can't run the Project. Please let me know is it Possible to run Xcode 4 Project in Xcode 3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode backward compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340401/xcode-backward-compatibility)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. Xcode4 saves the Xcode4 specific settings in a file that isn't used by Xcode3. But the project "layout" (which files should be compiled, compiler settings etc) is still in Xcode3 compatible files. And all the `.m`, `.h` `.xib` files are of course in the same format as in Xcode3

But since "I can't run the Project" isn't a helpful error description I can't help you further.

Comment: Matthias is there a workflow to be followed in order to get a xcodeproj made in Xcode4 running in Xcode3? Or should I always make a new project in Xcode3 and import all the files? Thanks